# Update Individual field in DB

Tags: android

I am Creating DB with three fields `name,id,mark`. I created table and inserted values using

`StudentDb.addStudentDetail(new StudentDetails(id,Name,0));`

I used Update method Like:

```
public int updateStudentDetail(StudentDetails student) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();`enter code here`
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("id", student.getID());
    values.put("name", student.getName());
    values.put("mark", student.getMark());
    int i = db.update(TABLE_STUDENT, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(student.getId()) });
    db.close();
    return i;
}
```

I call this method Like:

`StudentDb.updateStudentDetail(student);`

I don't know how to pass a value update method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its very simple. Lets say you want to update the marks of a student. Implement this in your `DatabaseHelper` class:

```
public int udpateStudentMarks(final int studentID,final int marks){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("mark", marks);
    int i = db.update(TABLE_STUDENT, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(studentID) });
    db.close();
    return i;
}
```

now you can use it like this:

```
db.updateStudentMarks(studID,newMarks);
```

Hope it helps.